# Facebook Taggable Friends

Tags: angularjs, cordova, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get all the friends of the user currently signed in. I tried /me/friends but that didn't work as it returns only the users using my app already. I then tried `https://graph.facebook.com/me/taggable_friends?access_token=somecodehere` 
In the browser it says

> "To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins,
>   developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be
>   reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review
>   please read our documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review"

But when I do a GET (using Angular.js) on this URL with a valid access token using my application, it returns me a list of my friends, with their id, name, picture. Why is this happening? How can my app get the data if my browser cannot?

Also, the picture currently returned is too small. How can I get the email and larger picture of all my friends in this response?

Any help is highly appreciated.

***PS: I am building a cordova app and getting access_token via CordovaOAuth.***

Answer (score 0):

`taggable_friends` works for you because it works without review for everyone with a role in the App (Admin/Developer/Tester). You only need to go through the review process if you want to go public with your App.

That beind said, `taggable_friends` is for tagging only, a larger picture is not neccessary for that and you definitely can´t get their email. What would you do with the email of friends who did not even authorized your App? You would not be allowed to use those emails anyway. You can ONLY get the email of a Facebook user by authorizing that user with the `email` permission.

More information about getting access to friends: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: I am already requesting email and friend_list then why is it not providing email in response?

Comment: because you can´t get the email of friends, for obvious reasons. and not sure what you mean with "friend_list", there is no permission called friend_list. there is only "user_friends", and you only get those who authorized your app too.

Comment: the main question is: what for do you need the friendlist and the email of friends?

Comment: I was just learning and trying to create a contacts app that uses facebook integration. So, I wanted emails of friends, amd later may be add their phone number.

Comment: read my answer again then. taggable_friends is for tagging only, nothing else. you would never get it approved for a contacts app. also, read the part about emails, you can never get the emails of friends, you can only get emails of authorized users. and you can´t get phone numbers at all, not even from the authorized user.

Comment: meaning, you could only create a contacts app between authorized users of your app, no one else will shop up and you can´t get the email of anyone else without explicit authorization.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. How long does it take to get reviewed?

Comment: "The review time estimate will change based on the requested permissions, ranging between 3 to 7 business days."